# How to properly use time.Parse to create a time object from a Unix time string?

Tags: go

We are trying to parse a unix timestamp, which is available as a string, into a time object, however, the following does not work:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, "1393344464")
    fmt.Printf("%v", t)
}
```

It keeps returning 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC. [Go Playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/aBgqKgD3MF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have an error and you're not checking it: http://play.golang.org/p/7ruFfv5QHT which is bad practice (these errors are helpful for debugging! :) use them!)

UnixDate is for unix string representations of dates; not timestamps. From the source: `UnixDate = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"`.

Use `time.Unix`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Unix(1393324260, 0)
    fmt.Printf("%v", t)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/gj_4EtiOVY

Answer (score 5):

Preface — never ignore the `error` (`t, _ :=`), you'll miss the critical error message and be confused all the time.

About you problem — you need to use [time.Unix](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) to achieve what you want.

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  t, err := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, "1393344464")
  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
  }
  log.Printf("%v\n", t)

  t = time.Unix(1393344464,0)
  log.Printf("%v\n", t)
}
```